# What is setting my IPv6 addr_gen_mode?

Tags: networking, network-manager, system, ipv6

I have just implemented my own DynDNS service that updates the AAAA records with my DNS provider using an IPv6 prefix and a bunch of MAC addresses of LXD container macvlan interfaces. This works well.

Now I wanted to do the same with a few client machines on the network, but it seems that my Kubuntu 20.04 notebook does not generate its IPv6 address from EUI-64. Indeed, `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/addr_gen_mode` contains 1.
I do not quite understand what this means, but the resulting address is not made from the MAC in any obvious way.

I echoed 0 into the file and also set

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.addr_gen_mode = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s31f6.addr_gen_mode = 0
```

in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but as soon as I disable and reenable the connection via NetworkManager, `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp0s31f6/addr_gen_mode` is back to 1. What is causing this behavior?

Comment: `systemd-networkd` and probably `/etc/sysctl.d/40-ipv6.conf`  Please do not use old editing methods on systemd systems, systemd has its own configuration.

Comment: Hm, there is no such file and the other don't contain it. There is actually even a soft link from 99-sysctl.conf to /etc/sysctl.conf.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html says that if IPv6LinkLocalAddressGenerationMode isn't set, then the kernel default is used. I don't see it set anywhere, but something is messing with the kernel default from sysctl.

Comment: Might it be the same as https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/15465  ?  Oh and did you check for `/etc/sysctl.d/40-ipv6.conf`  or `/etc/sysctl.d/*-ipv6.conf`? The 40 is for execution order and could be another number.

Comment: Could be. Yes, I don't have such a file. The only ipv6 related filenam is 10-ipv6-privacy.conf. I also grep'ed the whole directory for that config. That one file contains net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2

Comment: @Rinzwind This is bull. systemd-networkd is completely optional, and kernel settings are not 'old editing methods'. They are used by systemd-networkd as well, which is great for servers and non-graphical systems. Network-Manager is still the best way to configure the network on desktop systems.

Comment: @mcandril That man page does not apply here, because systemd-networkd is normally not enabled on Ubuntu systems. Instead, Network-Manager is used, and Network-Manager "messes" with the settings, adjusting them to connection settings.

Answer (score 2):

Network-Manager causes it. It manages its own configuration for every connection and configures your adapter to suit its needs. If you want it to use eui64 on your network, configure the connection accordingly. You may also make it the default by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, adding this:

```
[connection]
ipv6.addr-gen-mode=eui64
```

From `man 5 NetworkManager.conf`:

> ```
>    CONNECTION SECTION
>
>    Specify default values for connections.
>
>    Such default values are only consulted if the corresponding
>    per-connection property explicitly allows for that. That means, all
>    these properties correspond to a property of the connection profile
>    (for example connection.mud-url). Only if the per-profile property is
>    set to a special value that indicates to use the default, the default
>    value from NetworkManager.conf is consulted. It depends on the
>    property, which is the special value that indicates fallback to the
>    default, but it usually is something like empty, unset values or
>    special numeric values like 0 or -1. That means the effectively used
>    value can first always be configured for each profile, and these
>    default values only matter if the per-profile values explicitly
>    indicates to use the default from NetworkManager.conf.
>
>    Example:
>
>        [connection]
>        ipv6.ip6-privacy=0
> ```